# Finding the max _length of word using MapReduce

Tags: python, list, dictionary, mapreduce, max

I need to find all the longest word/words from a txt file using MapReduce.
I have written the following code for the mapper and reducer, but it shows the entire dictionary of len(words) as Key and the words as Values.
I need help in writing the code to show the result of the max length only and the respective words.
Following is my code :

```
"""mapper.py"""
import sys
> for line in sys.stdin:
>   for word in line.strip().split():
>      print ('%s\t%s' % (len(word), word))



"""reducer.py"""

> import sys results={} for line in sys.stdin:
>     index, value = line.strip().split('\t')
>     if index not in results :
>         results[index] = value
>     else :
>         results[index] += ' '
>         results[index] += value
```

***** I m just stuck on this part to continue the coding to get the max(key) with corresponding words

Input file :
How Peace Begins ?
Peace begins with saying sorry,
Peace begins with not hurting others,
Peace begins with honesty ,trust and dedications,
Peace begins with showing cooperation and respect.
World Peace Begins with Me !

Output expected :
The longest word has 11 characters. The words are: dedications cooperation

Comment: What does your input look like?

Comment: input is a csv file with texts

Comment: In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you provide a minimal reproducible problem set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the example. What you have provided falls short of this goal. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have added the information @itprorh66.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are doing with the `stdin` or why you are importing `sys`. Also, the sample input file doesn't seem to be in csv format but just a simple text file.  As I understand you problem, you want to read an input file, measure the length of each word and report out the length of the maximum word or words and list the words meeting this criteria.  With this in mind, this is how I would proceed:

```
inputFile = r'sampleMapperText.txt'
with open(inputFile, 'r') as f:
    reslt = dict()  #keys = word lengths, values = words of key length
    text = f.read().split('\n')
    for line in text:
        words = line.split()
        for w in words:
            wdlist = reslt.pop(len(w), [])
            wdlist.append(w)
            reslt[len(w)] = wdlist
    maxLen = max(list(reslt.keys()))
    print(f"Max Word Length = {maxLen}, Longest words = {', '.join(reslt[maxLen])}")
```

Running this code produces:

```
Max Word Length = 12, Longest words = dedications,
```

If you insist on separating the process into two separate files. Assuming the two files are in the same directory, I would do it as follows:

The contents of the reducer.py file would be:

```
# reducer.py 
def getData(filepath: str) -> list([str]):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        text = f.read().split('\n')
    return text
```

The contents of the mapper.py file would be:

```
# mapper.py
from reducer import getData

def mapData(text:list(str)):
    reslt = dict()  #keys = word lengths, values = words of key length
    for line in text:
        words = line.split()
        for w in words:
            wdlist = reslt.pop(len(w), [])
            wdlist.append(w)
            reslt[len(w)] = wdlist
    maxLen = max(list(reslt.keys()))
    print(f"Max Word Length = {maxLen}, Longest words = {', '.join(reslt[maxLen])}")     

inputFile = r'sampleMapperText.txt'
mapData(getData(inputFile))
```

Comment: **stdin** and **sys** refers to the edu.platform which currently I'm using. Yes, you are right about the file type, I have keyed in by mistake. I need to split the task of finding the largest length of word in two steps ie.**mapper.py** and **reducer.py** and will have to do the coding accordingly so that the results output is what the task requires. The mapper code output shall produce the result and break it to the (key :value) pairs. I am just struggling to feed codes to the reducer part and your code example is perfect but I just don't know how to split part of it in reducery.py.

Comment: Some minor changes but the code worked perfectly and I got the output as required. the mapper.py comes before the reducer.py .